# How to prototype a duplicate prototype method for Array in javascript

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I'm trying to implement a duplicate method to the js Array prototype which concats a duplicate of the array to itself like so:

```
[11,22,3,34,5,26,7,8,9].duplicate(); // [11,22,3,34,5,26,7,8,9,11,22,3,34,5,26,7,8,9]
```

Here's what I have, but it causes the browser to crash:

```
var array = [11,22,3,34,5,26,7,8,9];

Array.prototype.duplicate = function() {

  var j = this.length;

  for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    this[j] = this[i];
    j++;
  }

  return this;
}
```

I'm trying to do this using native JS as practice for iterations and algorithms so I'm trying to avoid built-in methods, if possible, so that I can get a clearer understanding of how things are being moved around.

Any ideas on why it is crashing and how I can optimize it?

Comment: Once you understand what you want to know I would just `return this.concat(this);`

Comment: @elclanrs: That is elegant, but a small but perhaps important difference is that it creates a new array instead of changing the current array.

Comment: @Guffa and this is just trying too hard: `this.splice.apply(this, [this.length, 0].concat(this))` :p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code inside the loop changes the length of the array, so it will just keep growing and you will never reach the end of it. Get the initial length of the array in a variable and use in the loop condition. You can use that as offset for the target index also instead of another counter:

```
var array = [11,22,3,34,5,26,7,8,9];

Array.prototype.duplicate = function() {

  var len = this.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    this[len + i] = this[i];
  }

  return this;
}
```

Comment: That makes sense, but why is len increasing which each iteration? It's not part of the iteration so I don't get how or when var len = this.length is being re-evaluated.

Comment: @doremi: The `length` property of the array is increasing when you add items to the array. In the original code you have `this.length` in the loop condition.

Comment: var len = this.length; Doesn't this just statically set len once? How/where is len being updated with the new length? I'd understand if len = this.length was inside the loop, but it isn't. That's the part I don't understand.

Comment: @doremi: It's not updated. The point of the `len` variable is that it contains the initial length of the array, and doesn't change when the length of the array changes.

Answer (score 1):

The length of the array is increasing with each element added so you can not use this as a terminator. Try this.

```
var j = this.length;

for(var i = 0; i < j; i++) {
    this[i+j] = this[i];
}
```

Comment: This is wrong and causes an endless loop. See @Guffa's response below about j constantly increasing.

Comment: @doremi: Notice that the `j++;` isn't included in this code, so it's not increasing, and thus works correctly. (I used a different variable name in my code to suggest that it was used differently from the `j` variable in the original code.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's simplest code

```
Array.prototype.duplicate = function () {
    var array = this;
    return array.concat(array);
};
```

Comment: Why not just `return this.concat(this);`?

Comment: Sure, we can do that! Thanks @GabrielTomitsuka

Answer (score 1):

Using Spread syntax;
In a method, **this** refers to the *owner object*.

```
Array.prototype.duplicate = function () {
    return [...this, ...this]
};
```

```js
let array = [1,2,3,4,5];

Array.prototype.duplicate = function () {
    return [...this, ...this]
};

console.log(array.duplicate());
```